# Get first middle and last 10 line on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have text on textbox and I want to get the first 10 middle 10 and last 10 line on the text box.

Example below uses 2 in order to not give long sample data

sample data

```
1.2
1.44
1.68
1.44
1.44
1.2
1.68
1.68
1.68
1.68
```

expected output

```
1.2
1.44
1.44
1.2
1.68
1.68
```

My attemp.

```
var source = txtProcessData.Lines;
                    var first = source.Take(2);
                    var last = source.Skip(source.Length - 2);

                    txtProcessData.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, first);
```

but has error:

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'

**Note** Data lines will be always be even number because I have condition for that. I also use 2 on sample.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: and what if there is an odd amount of lines? Anyway, i think you should make an attempt, this question is very low quality

Comment: Split by `Environment.NewLine`, work out how many you have (`.Length`), and work out which indexes of the string array you need to take the ones you require.

Comment: What if there is less than 6 elements?

Comment: @MichaelRandall its not working has error on split on system array

Comment: @xdtTransform i have other condition on that i just do not include that on my question

Comment: A [Mre] will be nice. It's unclear if you have issue getting taking the right element or joinning them back. Your error is because  the variable `first` is an `IEnumerable<string>` and `Join(String, String[])` expect an array. A simple `first.ToArray()` will solve the error.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IXGKV3

Comment: yes it works. my problem now is getting the middle 2

Comment: Well that's, "and what if there is an odd amount of lines?", Micheal 's question.. Given   3 elements, the 2 in the middle will be 1-2 or 2-3? You will have less issue getting the middle index once you have the answer to that question. finding the middle index will be easy it should be related to `L÷ 2`

Comment: line will always a even number incase of its odd amount of lines another proccess it will get all da lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple `Where`:

```
var source = txtProcessData.Lines;

var result = source
  .Where((value, index) => index <= 1 ||                     // first  2 lines
                           index >= source.Count - 2 ||      // last   2 lines
                           index == source.Count / 2 ||      // middle 2 lines
                           index == source.Count / 2 - 1);

// ToArray() - Early versions C# want string[] for string.Join
txtProcessData.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.ToArray());
```

Comment: what if i have 30 data and i want to get the middle 10 ?